# Is there a device manager for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, device-manager

I'm looking for a Debian/Ubuntu package that serves as a device manager, an application that allows me to see and modify hardware on my machine (ie. hard drives, network cards, etc.) through a visual interface.

I searched for one and found `gnome-device-manager`, however it seems to have been discontinued and is removed from the official repositories. I also searched the Ubuntu Software Centre but could not find any.

Does anybody know any alternatives I can use?

Answer (score 2):

One good device manager with benchmark capabilities is [HardInfo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardInfo):

**Key Features:**

- Comprehensive reports on hardware
- Generate HTML reports on your system's hardware
- Benchmark and compare your system.

[image]